# Home Connect SDK beta: CLIENT_NOT_INITIALIZED error

Tags: java, android, api, sdk, authorization

I am unsuccessfully trying to implement the HomeConnect SDK Beta v1.2.0 (https://developer.home-connect.com) into an Android app, in accordance to the documentation and analog to the provided example project.
Unfortunately, I can't get through the authorization flow, and keep encountering the error "CLIENT_NOT_INITIALIZED". I understand that the SDK is still in its beta phase, but maybe someone has already made some experience with it and can help me solve this problem.

For test purposes and to isolate the problem I created the following app.
I'm initializing the HomeConnect class in the Application override, pass my credentials in the onCreate() and set up a getter-method:

```
import android.app.Application;
import com.home_connect.sdk.Environment;
import com.home_connect.sdk.services.HomeConnect;

public class HCSignInDemoApplication extends Application {
private static HomeConnect mHomeConnect;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        mHomeConnect = new HomeConnect("signInDemo", this, "<MY_API_KEY>", Environment.SIMULATOR);
    }
    public static HomeConnect getHomeConnect() {
        return mHomeConnect;
    }
}
```

In the MainActivity's onCreate(), an OnClickListener of a button is calling an AuthorizationDialogFragment if the HomeConnect class is not yet authorized:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AuthorizationDialogFragment.OnAuthorizedCallback {

    Button loginButton;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        loginButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.loginBtn);

        loginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Log.d("MainActivity", "LoginButton clicked");
                if(HCSignInDemoApplication.getHomeConnect().isAuthorized()){
                Log.d("MainActivity", "Is authorized");
                } else  {
                    Log.d("MainActivity", "Open HC AuthorizationDialogFragment");
                    new AuthorizationDialogFragment().show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "");
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onAuthorized() {
        Log.d("MainActivity", "onAuthorized called");
    }
}
```

On button click the following DialogFragment should open a WebView in which the user can enter email and password for his/her HomeConnect account and get an access token.

```
 import com.home_connect.sdk.exceptions.HomeConnectException;
 import com.home_connect.sdk.internal.util.TextUtil;
 import com.home_connect.sdk.model.Permission;
 import com.home_connect.sdk.property.RxBinder;
 import com.home_connect.sdk.services.HomeConnect;
 import java.util.Set;
 import rx.functions.Action1;

 /**
 * {@link DialogFragment} which is shown at the authorization process
 */
public class AuthorizationDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

    private WebView mWebView;
    private OnAuthorizedCallback onAuthorizedCallback;

    public interface OnAuthorizedCallback {
        void onAuthorized();
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NO_FRAME, R.style.AppTheme);
    }
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        mWebView = new WebView(inflater.getContext());
        return mWebView;
    }
    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();
        mWebView = null;
    }
    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        if (context instanceof OnAuthorizedCallback) {
            onAuthorizedCallback = (OnAuthorizedCallback) context;
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        onAuthorizedCallback = null;
    }
    /**
     * set the {@link Permission} scopes and make a Token request via {@link HomeConnect}
     */
    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        Set<Permission> scopes = Permission.createScope(
            Permission.IDENTIFY_APPLIANCE
        );

        RxBinder.bind(this
            , HCSignInDemoApplication.getHomeConnect().requestToken(mWebView, scopes)
            , new Action1<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void call(Void aVoid) {
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "token request successful!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    if (onAuthorizedCallback != null) {
                        onAuthorizedCallback.onAuthorized();
                    }
                }
            }
            , new Action1<Throwable>() {
                @Override
                public void call(Throwable throwable) {
                    if (throwable instanceof HomeConnectException) {
                        HomeConnectException exception = (HomeConnectException) throwable;
                        showErrorDialog(exception);
                        dismiss();
                    }
                }
            }
        );
    }

    /**
     * Necessary call to unbind the {@link RxBinder} to avoid memory leaks
     */
    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        RxBinder.unbind(this);
    }

    protected void showErrorDialog(@Nullable HomeConnectException error) {
        Log.i("HCAuthDialogFragment", "Error: " + error);
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        builder.setTitle(R.string.error);
        if (error != null && error.apiError != null && !TextUtil.isEmpty(error.apiError.description)) {
            builder.setMessage(error.apiError.description);
        } else if (error != null && !TextUtil.isEmpty(error.description)) {
            builder.setMessage(error.description);
        } else if (error != null && !TextUtil.isEmpty(error.httpMessage)) {
            builder.setMessage(error.httpMessage);
        } else {
            builder.setMessage(R.string.unknown_error);
        }
        builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, null);
        AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
        alertDialog.show();
    }
}
```

Ok, so what happens instead of the expected WebView dialog is an AlertDialog with the error code "CLIENT_NOT_INITIALIZED" and the description "The client hasn't been initialized. Please make sure your API key and redirect URL are correct".
API key is definitely correct, but I don't actively pass the redirect URL at any point, nor do I have the option to.
The full log reads like this:

```
Connected to process 3108 on device Nexus_5_API_24 [emulator-5554]
I/art: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
W/art: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86_64
E/art: Failed sending reply to debugger: Broken pipe
I/art: Debugger is no longer active
I/art: Starting a blocking GC Instrumentation
W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/android.test.net.hcsignindemo-1/lib/x86_64
I/InstantRun: Instant Run Runtime started. Android package is android.test.net.hcsignindemo, real application class is android.test.net.hcsignindemo.HCSignInDemoApplication.
W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/android.test.net.hcsignindemo-1/lib/x86_64
D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
W/art: Verification of java.lang.Object android.support.v7.appcompat.R$attr.access$super(android.support.v7.appcompat.R$attr, java.lang.String, java.lang.Object[]) took 708.872ms
I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 20350(3MB) AllocSpace objects, 18(348KB) LOS objects, 39% free, 6MB/10MB, paused 5.598ms total 1.051s
I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 1
E/EGL_emulation: tid 3224: eglSurfaceAttrib(1146): error 0x3009 (EGL_BAD_MATCH)
W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0x72c1e3a56900, error=EGL_BAD_MATCH
I/Choreographer: Skipped 88 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
D/MainActivity: LoginButton clicked
D/MainActivity: Open HC AuthorizationDialogFragment
W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /system/app/webview/lib/x86_64
I/WebViewFactory: Loading com.android.webview version 52.0.2743.100 (code 275610060)
I/cr_LibraryLoader: Time to load native libraries: 59 ms (timestamps 4797-4856)
I/cr_LibraryLoader: Expected native library version number "52.0.2743.100", actual native library version number "52.0.2743.100"
V/WebViewChromiumFactoryProvider: Binding Chromium to main looper Looper (main, tid 1) {a14c6d}
I/cr_LibraryLoader: Expected native library version number "52.0.2743.100", actual native library version number "52.0.2743.100"
I/chromium: [INFO:library_loader_hooks.cc(143)] Chromium logging enabled: level = 0, default verbosity = 0
I/cr_BrowserStartup: Initializing chromium process, singleProcess=true
W/cr_media: Requires BLUETOOTH permission
I/cr_DRP: No DRP key due to exception:java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.android.webview.chromium.Drp
W/cr_AwContents: onDetachedFromWindow called when already detached. Ignoring
I/ANDROID.TEST.NET.HCSIGNINDEMO: (InitializeCall.java:40) createRequest: main creating init request...
I/Choreographer: Skipped 108 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
E/EGL_emulation: tid 3224: eglSurfaceAttrib(1146): error 0x3009 (EGL_BAD_MATCH)
W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0x72c1e3a56c00, error=EGL_BAD_MATCH
I/Choreographer: Skipped 34 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
W/art: Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread
I/art: Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 14247(1514KB) AllocSpace objects, 6(120KB) LOS objects, 21% free, 14MB/18MB, paused 2.204ms total 127.182ms
I/ANDROID.TEST.NET.HCSIGNINDEMO: (InitializeCall.java:57) onJsonServerResponse: RxCachedThreadScheduler-1 handling init...
I/ANDROID.TEST.NET.HCSIGNINDEMO: (RequestSimulatorAuthorizationCall.java:36) createRequest: RxCachedThreadScheduler-1 creating simulator token request...
I/ANDROID.TEST.NET.HCSIGNINDEMO: (HttpApiCallClient.java:197) addInitializationInfo: RxCachedThreadScheduler-2 adding init info...
I/ANDROID.TEST.NET.HCSIGNINDEMO: (HCUtils.java:79) call: main retry attempt
I/HCAuthDialogFragment: Error: com.home_connect.sdk.exceptions.HomeConnectException: Description: The client hasn't been initialized. Please make sure your API key and redirect URL are correct
                    Error code: CLIENT_NOT_INITIALIZED
E/EGL_emulation: tid 3224: eglSurfaceAttrib(1146): error 0x3009 (EGL_BAD_MATCH)
W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0x72c1e3a56c00, error=EGL_BAD_MATCH
Application terminated.
```

The HomeConnect SDK documentation has a trouble shooting section, but unfortunately doesn't include the occuring error.
Am I missing something essential here or could it be, that the current version of the SDK is not runnable yet?

**What does work:**
HomeConnect offers an API client with a swagger UI (https://apiclient.home-connect.com/). With the help of the chrome development tool and Postman I was able to find out the client_secret (which I couldn't find anywhere in the documentation).
With that it is possible to get a valid access token through HttpURLconnection, which allows to get a JSON response with an array of example appliances. But this misses the point of using the SDK.

```
//!!!!!! TEST !!!!!!
//get access_token through client_secret
private class PostRequestForToken extends AsyncTask<String, Void, HCAccessTokenModel> {

    @Override
    protected HCAccessTokenModel doInBackground(String... params) {

        HttpURLConnection connection = null;
        BufferedReader reader = null;

        try{
            // Open connection and handle request (OutputStream)
            URL url = new URL(params[0]);           // ParamsArray[0] is url address, needs to be "https://developer.home-connect.com/security/oauth/token"
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setReadTimeout(10000);
            connection.setConnectTimeout(15000);
            connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.setDoOutput(true);

            Uri.Builder builder = new Uri.Builder()
                    .appendQueryParameter("client_id", "<MY_API_KEY>")          // API key from https://developer.home-connect.com/?q=user/my_apps
                    .appendQueryParameter("code", "96b5673f5e56eb9efba9424f94d5c0958377185767d6f2711f53d72c7ba4bb7f")               // redirect from https://developer.home-connect.com/security/oauth/authorize?client_id=<YOUR API KEY HERE>&redirect_uri=https://apiclient.home-connect.com/o2c.html&response_type=code&scope=IdentifyAppliance
                    .appendQueryParameter("grant_type", "authorization_code")
                    .appendQueryParameter("redirect_uri", "https://apiclient.home-connect.com/o2c.html")                            // redirect URL set in https://developer.home-connect.com/?q=user/my_apps
                    .appendQueryParameter("client_secret", "C8DED1367FEEFDE94C1390B6B3EC3EE9397A78943A6BA18CB416A430A0DE696F");      // retrieved through URL log on Swagger UI

            String query = builder.build().getEncodedQuery();

            OutputStream os = connection.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                    new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
            writer.write(query);
            writer.flush();
            writer.close();
            os.close();

            connection.connect();

            // Handle response (InputStream)
            InputStream stream = connection.getInputStream();
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));
            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();

            String line = "";
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
                buffer.append(line);
            }

            String finalJson = buffer.toString();
            // Parse to JSON Object
            JSONObject parentObject = new JSONObject(finalJson);

            HCAccessTokenModel tokenModel = new HCAccessTokenModel();
            tokenModel.setAccess_token(parentObject.getString("access_token"));
            tokenModel.setExpires_in(parentObject.getString("expires_in"));
            tokenModel.setId_token(parentObject.getString("id_token"));
            tokenModel.setRefresh_token(parentObject.getString("refresh_token"));
            tokenModel.setScope(parentObject.getString("scope"));
            tokenModel.setToken_type(parentObject.getString("token_type"));


            return tokenModel;
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (connection != null) {
                connection.disconnect();
            }
        } try {
            if (reader != null){
                reader.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(HCAccessTokenModel tokenModel) {
        super.onPostExecute(tokenModel);
        Log.d(TAG, "token_type: " + tokenModel.getToken_type() + "\naccess_token: " + tokenModel.getAccess_token());
        new GetRequestForApplianceList().execute("https://developer.home-connect.com/api/homeappliances", tokenModel.getToken_type(), tokenModel.getAccess_token());
    }
}

private class GetRequestForApplianceList extends AsyncTask<String, Void, List<HCApplianceModel>> {

    @Override
    protected List<HCApplianceModel> doInBackground(String... params) {

        HttpURLConnection connection = null;
        BufferedReader reader = null;

        try {
            // Open connection
            URL url = new URL(params[0]);           // ParamsArray[0] is url address, needs to be "https://developer.home-connect.com/api/homeappliances"
            String token_type = params[1];          // ParamsArray[1] is token type, needs to be "Bearer"
            String access_token = params[2];        // ParamsArray[2]
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setReadTimeout(10000);
            connection.setConnectTimeout(15000);
            connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", token_type + " " + access_token);
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/vnd.bsh.sdk.v1+json");
            connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 ( compatible ) ");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "*/*");

            //connection.connect();
            Log.d(TAG, "Connected");

            // Handle response (InputStream)
            InputStream stream = new BufferedInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));
            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();

            String line = "";
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                buffer.append(line);
            }

            String finalJson = buffer.toString();
            // Parse to JSON Array
            JSONObject parentObject = new JSONObject(finalJson);
            JSONArray parentArray = parentObject.getJSONObject("data").getJSONArray("homeappliances");         //"homeappliances" is key of JSONArray

            List<HCApplianceModel> applianceModelList = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int i = 0; i < parentArray.length(); i++) {

                JSONObject finalObject = parentArray.getJSONObject(i);

                HCApplianceModel applianceModel = new HCApplianceModel();
                applianceModel.setHaId(finalObject.getString("haId"));
                applianceModel.setVib(finalObject.getString("vib"));
                applianceModel.setBrand(finalObject.getString("brand"));
                applianceModel.setType(finalObject.getString("type"));
                applianceModel.setName(finalObject.getString("name"));
                applianceModel.setEnumber(finalObject.getString("enumber"));
                applianceModel.setConnected(finalObject.getBoolean("connected"));

                applianceModelList.add(applianceModel);
            }

            return applianceModelList;           // This is result passed to onPostExecute(List<HCApplianceModel> applianceModels)

        } catch (ProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (connection != null) {
                connection.disconnect();
            }
        }
        try {
            if (reader != null) {
                reader.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<HCApplianceModel> applianceModels) {
        super.onPostExecute(applianceModels);
        // Set TextView for testing
        String message = "";
        for (int j = 0; j < applianceModels.size(); j++){
            message += "haId: " + applianceModels.get(j).getHaId() + "\n";
            message += "vib: " + applianceModels.get(j).getVib() + "\n";
            message += "brand: " + applianceModels.get(j).getBrand() + "\n";
            message += "type: " + applianceModels.get(j).getType() + "\n";
            message += "name: " + applianceModels.get(j).getName() + "\n";
            message += "enumber: " + applianceModels.get(j).getEnumber() + "\n";
            message += "connected: " + applianceModels.get(j).isConnected() + "\n" + "\n";

        }

        textView.setText(message);

    }

}
```

Comment: Did you succeed in this?